# Match all lines where the text is not surrounded by a specific set of characters

Tags: regex, notepad++, wikitext

I'm trying to do a find-replace (in Notepad++, but the specific tool may not matter) for certain entries in a document. The document has entries that look something like this:

```
==Some header==
* {{Tselect|Select an option}}
** This is an option.
*** '''Someone:''' The option will have some kind of response.
*** '''Someone else:''' Possibly even multiple lines of response.
** This is a different option.
*** {{Tact|This one has a different type of response, surrounded by brackets}}
```

In the above example, I only want to match `** This is an option.` and `** This is a different option.`, but none of the other lines.

Additionally, once I've captured that, I want to wrap the text (not the `*` characters) with the following: `{{Topt|The text}}`.

I would keep the same number of asterisks, and put the text following the asterisks inside of the `{{Topt|` and `}}`.

For example, I would turn `** This is an option.` into `** {{Topt|This is an option.}}`.

I've been fiddling with the regex in a regex tester, but it's matching either nothing or almost everything. I know it will need to start with `^(\*+)`  so that it only matches start of lines that have an unlimited number of asterisks followed by a space and so that I can capture the exact number of `*` characters, and it will need to end with `$` so that it's confined to a single line.

What I'm struggling with is how I can exclude anything where the text either starts with something surrounded by three `'` characters, and also anything surrounded by the `{{` and `}}` characters.

In case it's relevant, this is wiki-code syntax, and it's bulleted items that are slightly more indented at times.

Comment: "*in Notepad++, but the specific tool may not matter*" In regex the tool always matters (engines are very different). Good you mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\*+ \K(?!{{|''').+$`
- Replace with: `{{Topt|$0}}`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
\*+         # 1 or more asterisks followed by a space
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
(?!{{|''')  # negative lookahead, make sure the text doesn't begin with {{ or '''
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
{{Topt|     # literally
$0          # the whole match (i.e. the text to be copied
}}          # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]